# What is causing the Stack Smashing error in my C++ program?

Tags: c++

I am in the process of learning C++ and I ran into a "Stack Smashing" error when I attempted to create a simple multiplication table using an array of integers (as shown below). The code executes successfully, but at the bottom I am told "Stack Smashing Detected".

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

```
int timesTable[10][10] = {};

for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        timesTable[i][j] = i * j;
        if (j == 10) {
            cout << timesTable[i][j] << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << timesTable[i][j] << ", " << flush;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Indices should go from 0 to 9!

Comment: *The code executes successfully* -- No it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C++ are indexed from zero, so your loops should be from 0 to 10 instead of from 1 to 11. Your current program goes out of array range and thus exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Wow. I definitely should have seen that. lol
Thanks for the help! You were right on the money.